# Algorithm for out-of-area point classification

Tags: algorithms, classification

I have a device that sends its coordinates every 30 seconds. When I receive the coordinates, I classify the point as either belonging to (ie being inside) one of a number of predefined areas (so I assign an area number > 0 to it), or an "external" point (indicated by area -1).

External points can be caused, essentially, by two reasons:

1) The device is moving and is currently between two areas, so if moving from area 100 to area 78 there will be a sequence like 100, ... 100, -1, -1, ..., -1, 78, 78, 78... The sequence of -1's will be longer or shorter depending on the distance between the two areas and the device speed.

2) The device is close to an area's border and due to the limited precision of the device's GPS it may look like sometimes the device is entering and exiting the area, so it will be something like 99, -1, 99, 99, -1, -1, 99, 99... until it finally settles back to a steady run of 99's when the device moves further back into the area (or moves to another area, in which case we have case 1) above).

At the end of the day, I have a list of (timestamp, coordinates, area) entries (about 2500 points, encompassing an unknown number of areas, depending on how the device moved during the day).

Now my need is to classify external points (area == -1) and forcefully assign them to some real area. So for example for case 1), half (more or less) of the -1's should be assigned to area 100, the other half to area 78, while for case 2) all of the -1's should be assigned to area 99.
Of course this reclassification will be done when the complete data for the day is available, not in real time.

I just need some starting point about how to tackle the problem or existing algorithms that can do the job, then I'll do my research. Thanks.

Comment: The simplest solution is to assign -1 to the previous non-(-1) point.

Comment: Well yes, previous or "closer" (forwards backwards), that's a way to do it (and thanks, because I hadn't thought of this - now obvious - method). When I wrote the question I was thinking some complicated clustering stuff but your suggestion makes perfect sense.